# Animated gif while using the Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, gif, animated-gif

I have an image as a gif that I want to be able to control via the keyboard keys, and for a while I used a picturebox to do this. I've switched to the Graphics.DrawImage method however, as I've realised that I can't move the picturebox without causing background transparency issues. I've now realised that using the Graphics.DrawImage method means that the gif doesn't animate. I think I *could* just separate the gif and change each of the pictures using a timer, but that seems like it would take up more space and processing power than just having a simple gif.

Is there a way I can animate the gif simply? Or will I have to change the pictures?
My code to display the image is this:

```
Bitmap Picture = Properties.Resources.MarioWalkLeft;
int _x = 100, _y = 100;
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Picture.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Picture, _x, _y);
}
```

Comment: Just make the gif a background image `PictureBox1.Image = Picture`

Comment: I can't use a picturebox because when I try to move it I get a stuttering effect in the background. When I move a picturebox I end up with [this](http://i.imgur.com/zk2Qyl1.png). Using Graphics.DrawImage fixes the stuttering problem, but then my gif isn't animated.

Comment: You said *Is there a way I can animate the gif simply?* that is why i replied.

Comment: I just saw the image. It is game so you defenitely need to open the gif and draw the images your self. You surely gain in performance. But dont use the picturebox solution. Draw directly on the form.

Comment: Use the ImageAnimator class.  Start with the sample code shown in the MSDN Library article for it.

Comment: I've tried using that, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've even tried directly copy-pasting the code into a new program to see if it works, only to find my image remaining static.